# Creating a bar plot with both compounding and stacked bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataframe with different age groups and the counts of indigenous and non indigenous population counts. I want to create a compound bar plot with a bar representing the status of the population (indigenous or not) while the genders are stacked on each bar as well.

I managed to create the bar plots separately but am unsure how to put them together.

```
age_group gender status           count
 <chr>     <chr>  <chr>            <dbl>
  0-4       Male   Indigenous       37768
  0-4       Female Indigenous       35496
  0-4       Both   Indigenous       73265
  0-4       Male   Non Indigenous  673289
  0-4       Female Non Indigenous  638089
  0-4       Both   Non Indigenous 1311383


aus_age_cat_counts %>%
  filter(gender %in% c("Male", "Female")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age_group, y = count, fill = gender)) +
  geom_col(position="fill")
```

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer at the moment, but you could try two geoms: one with total, and then male (or female) on top of it. It will look as if they're stacked. I'll try to provide some code later.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use `position="fill"`, you should have both informations you need (a count of status and the distribution of gender within each category). Are you looking for something like that?

```
# load functions
"%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"
# set seed and create fake data
seed(1312)
n <- 5000
d <- dplyr::tibble(AGE_GRP=sample(seq(1,100,10),
                                  size=n,
                                  replace=T,
                                  prob=dbinom(1:10,10,0.5)),
                   GENDER=sample(c("Male","Female"),
                                 size=n,
                                 replace=T,
                                 prob=c(.45,.55)),
                   STATUS=sample(c("I","Non-I"),
                                 size=n,
                                 replace=T,
                                 prob=c(.6,.4)))

# plot data
d %>%
  dplyr::count(AGE_GRP,GENDER,STATUS,name="N") %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=STATUS, y=N, fill=GENDER)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col() + 
  ggplot2::theme_minimal()
```

[image]